# This Alpine town?

Tags: where-on-earth, locate-this

https://wallpapershome.com/nature/alps-switzerland-europe-mountains-trees-sky-clouds-8k-16935.html

[image]

It would seem to be by [this](https://felix-mittermeier.de/?ref=pexels) photographer, F. Mittermeier

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is not Switzerland, as the page you are linking to claims, but the picture is from Berchtesgaden in Germany. The largest peak in the background to the right is the Watzmann.

At least most of it. There has been done some really strange manipulations of the image and I am not 100% sure if it is not at least partially a collage put together from different pictures, perhaps also different locations. The sky looks unreal enough to perhaps be computer generated.

Looking at some of the details in the image, e.g. the top of the three church towers to the right have been removed:

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90854/discussion-on-answer-by-tor-einar-jarnbjo-this-alpine-town).

Comment: It's funny - now that you've pointed out it's a composite, it is now quite obvious it is a composite, and, I can only "see" it that way!  Heh!

Answer (score 5):

I emailed the photographer via his Contact page, and asked if it's a real city, or if it's a "collage" of multiple - he said (translated from German):

> Yes, this is a real city in the Bavarian Alps - more precisely "Berchtesgaden" [Germany].

Edit: You can see a very similar photo [on Google Maps' "side images"](https://www.google.com/maps/place/83471+Berchtesgaden,+Germany/@47.6301796,13.0000742,3a,75y,90t/data=!3m8!1e2!3m6!1shttp:%2F%2Ft3.gstatic.com%2Fimages%3Fq%3Dtbn:ANd9GcRKNXabCHVcNQJDxqzmd_sK1l16WLG4RRHZ6O2fldpnOETjMSue!2e7!3e27!6s%2F%2Flh3.googleusercontent.com%2Fproxy%2FWITVFDXIJMQQKWbOpow1LOE_LpybGV0MNomJU2B0oLpmn0Ju84xg5-fqr_iMHNhW5ld5wgXzaKT5KN6IBD6nDhD4fFJHmSvPsxZYfKvEsQEonaeQ1dMG6IBq72Iqv3VVpqe0Lqr02W3urQK_5ASj9VJIl5sAClQ%3Dw203-h135-k-no!7i1080!8i720!4m5!3m4!1s0x4776eb5da8d79dd3:0x41d25a40937b770!8m2!3d47.6301796!4d13.0000742) and it definitely is Berchtesgaden, but I do agree some editing seemed to be done.

Comment: Thanks for the first-hand information!  Spectacular!   Yes, it is surely heavily edited.  On second glance, the town to the lower left: the perspective is totally wrong.  A fascinating image from a great photographer!